# React props are not working into for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, components, react-props

When i pass rating as props to Star Rating component i can find rating value in StarRating function but in whenever it goes to for loop rating become invisible.

```
import React from 'react'

const StarRating = ({ rating }) => {
const stars = [];
for (let j; j <= 5; j++) {
    if (j <= 3) {
        stars.push(<i className="fas fa-start"></i>);
    } else if (j === Math.ceil(rating) && !Number.isInteger(rating)) {
        stars.push(<i className="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>);
    } else {
        stars.push(<i className="fas fa-star"></i>);
    }
}
return (
    <div>
        {stars}
    </div>
)
}

export default StarRating
```

Answer (score 0):

"j" must be initialized in your For Loop.

```
for(let j = 1;j <=5; j++)
{ 
  /*your logic here*/ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the destructing object using the spread operator like {...rating} and also initialization of variable in loop is mandatory.

```
import React from 'react'

const StarRating = ({...rating }) => {
const stars = [];
for (let j=0; j <= 5; j++) {
    if (j <= 3) {
        stars.push(<i className="fas fa-start"></i>);
    } else if (j === Math.ceil(rating) && !Number.isInteger(rating)) {
        stars.push(<i className="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>);
    } else {
        stars.push(<i className="fas fa-star"></i>);
    }
}
return (
    <div>
        {stars}
    </div>
)
}

export default StarRating
```